# How to have Android Studio generate R.java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Today I've been struggling to get my Android Application to work in Android Studio. I've imported the project from an Eclipse project. However, the wrong R.java file is created.

Everywhere in the code the R is red: `Cannot resolve symbol "R"`. And when hovering the import statement (`import com.example.myproject.R;`): `Unused import statement`. I do not know where the `R.java` is created or should be located, but here's my guess: `$MODULE$/build/generated/source/r/debug/com/example/myproject/R.java`.
That is, because the `$MODULE/build/generated/source/r/release/com/example/myproject/R.java` is being generated, but not the `/debug/` version. If I copy the `/release/` R.java file to the `/debug/com/example/myproject/` directory, all errors solve themselves. **But how can I make Android Studio to always generated the `/debug/` R.java file?**

The myproject.iml file shows:

```
<facet type="android" name="Android">
  <configuration>
    <option name="SELECTED_BUILD_VARIANT" value="debug" />
.... etc..
```

So why is the R.java in the release folder generated?

Comment: Did you check your xml files? Any error there? Try to rebuild and clean your project.

Comment: try to run assembleDebug and check the errors

Comment: I have a similar problem. With a 'normal' project build, the debug R generated files are missing. If I select the library project and then 'Build->Make Module', the debug R is generated.

Comment: I  ended up removing the library project and reconfiguring it. It 'magically' worked after this...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the

```
<facet type="java-gradle" name="Java-Gradle">
```

part is strangely missing in my .iml file

```
...
<facet type="android-gradle" name="Android-Gradle">
  <configuration>
    <option name="GRADLE_PROJECT_PATH" value=":listpopupmenu" />
  </configuration>
</facet>
<facet type="java-gradle" name="Java-Gradle">
  <configuration>
    <option name="BUILD_FOLDER_PATH" value="$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    <option name="BUILDABLE" value="false" />
  </configuration>
</facet>
<facet type="android" name="Android">
...
```

after adding that part, it works as expected.